# Another Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-clues

This one probably isn't so tough either.  (Why do I have to write this stuff to meet "quality standards"?)

Errant mineralogist is a disheveled feminist. (6,7)

Comment: Doesn't this need another E (like a fish needs a bicycle)?

Comment: Does it?   (more letters.....)

Comment: Well, I thought it did, but I'm probably missing something somewhere else. Never mind.

Comment: I think the clue is valid.

Comment: 'Easiness' is not a reason to fail quality standards - bad posing of puzzles would be. However, I think cryptic clue puzzles would be 'better' if more than one is combined into a more complete puzzle, rather than posting each individual one as question...

Comment: @BmyGuest, I think the remark about quality standards is about a minimum-length limit on puzzle text.

Comment: Ah! Thanks. See [this meta post](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5097/tag-merge-or-stricter-tagging-policy-cryptic-clues-and-cryptic-crosswords)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan is correct.  You have to write more characters to allow the question to post.

Comment: More annoying to me is the fact that you can never write a comment saying just something like "Exactly!" or "Right." or "No.".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I think this is **Exactly!** the reason this limit is in place ;c). To avoid endless, boring to read "me too" thanks etc. That's what the comment-upvote is for, after all.

Comment: Hmm. But people still do thank one another, they just do it at slightly greater length. An upvote doesn't fulfill the same purpose -- you thank someone so they'll know *you* appreciated what they did, whereas an upvote only tried then that *someone* did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is probably:

> [Gloria Steinem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_Steinem), well-known **feminist**. It is an anagram ("dishevelled") of E (for errant, I assume) and MINERALOGIST.
>
>  (I'm a bit skeptical about E for errant with no further indication to take the first letter only. And it is a bit unfortunate that "is a" separates the anagram indicator from the anagram fodder.)

Comment: I share your skepticism about the E.

Comment: Me too. The "is a" issue could perhaps be improved by making it "Disheveled errant mineralogist is a feminist".

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan: Good idea. And you could get rid of errant with "English mineralogist" or "low-grade mineralogist" or perhaps "mineralogist, head of expedition".